# Error in while((Status.health !0) && (Wolves.health !0) ) expected expression ")"

Tags: c++, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Hey i have an error in this:

```
while((Status.health !0) && (Wolves.health !0) )
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's syntactically incorrect.

Assuming you want to verify that the variables are not equal to zero:

```
while((Status.health != 0) && (Wolves.health != 0) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you mean

```
while((Status.health != 0) && (Wolves.health != 0) )
```